# Ajax problem using MooTools/jQuery - p.onStatusChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, firebug

I get the following error in firebug in Firefox 3 with both MooTools and jQuery:
"p.onStatusChange is not a function".

I've noticed this error frequently in firebug since one of the latest updates of FF3.  However, it has started appearing with code that hasn't been changed in some time and that was not reporting errors previously.  The errors happens when ajax results are returned.  It shows up in different applications that use separate javascript libraries, MooTools and jQuery.

Does anyone have any idea why these errors are appearing?  My intuition tells me that it is something in Firefox that changed, but I can't find any information online currently.  The ajax calls still work fine, but I am wary of just going with my intuition and leaving script errors in my code.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: I'm not sure, they're in the minified javascript libraries for MooTools and jQuery, not my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reference for the function [NsIDownloadProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDownloadProgressListener).  It looks like it has been deprecated.

Comment: I think this is it, thanks.  I'll see about submitting a bug report and then let the libraries catch up.

Answer (score 3):

I get it in tabBrowser instead:
chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml

(4) errors occur:

p.onStatusChange

p.onProgressChange

p.onStateChange

p.onSecurityChange

What I found was that the add-on "PDF Download" was causing these errors.  The best way for me to check was to go to a page that produced the errors, turn off all the add-ons, and turn them on one-by-one (starting with Firebug).  Instead of going one-by-one, I actually turned them on in lots of 3 to help identify the problem sooner.

Comment: I was having the same issue.  Disabling the add-on got rid of the errors.

Comment: Mozilla has a place to submit bugs, but I never used the add-on really anyhow, so I don't think I ever notified them.